# pagination in html table using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, pagination

I am working on pagination in HTML table using j query. i am able to achieve the pagination but currently the "Next" "Previous" "Next" "Last" are showing in text(kindly check the fiddle), I want to display it as a button, i am not sure how we can achieve it. kindly help.

Also i want to move the pager to right corner of the table. kindly help..

i have created a fiddle for this here is a link to it.

http://jsfiddle.net/q6u0rdsc/1/

HTML Code

```
 <table class="paginated">
     <thead>
         <tr>
             <th scope="col">A</th>
             <th scope="col">B</th>  
             <th scope="col">C</th> 
             <th scope="col">D</th>
         </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
       <tr>
     <td>0</td>
     <td>2</td>
     <td>3</td>
     <td>4</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td>5</td>
     <td>6</td>
     <td>7</td>
     <td>8</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td>9</td>
     <td>10</td>
     <td>11</td>
     <td>12</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td>13</td>
     <td>14</td>
     <td>15</td>
     <td>16</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td>17</td>
     <td>18</td>
     <td>19</td>
     <td>20</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td>21</td>
     <td>22</td>
     <td>23</td>
     <td>24</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td>25</td>
     <td>26</td>
     <td>27</td>
     <td>28</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td>29</td>
     <td>30</td>
     <td>31</td>
     <td>32</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td>33</td>
     <td>34</td>
     <td>35</td>
     <td>36</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td>37</td>
     <td>38</td>
     <td>39</td>
     <td>40</td>
 </tr> 
 <tr>
     <td>41</td>
     <td>42</td>
     <td>43</td>
     <td>34</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td>45</td>
     <td>46</td>
     <td>47</td>
     <td>48</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td>49</td>
     <td>50</td>
     <td>51</td>
     <td>52</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td>53</td>
     <td>54</td>
     <td>55</td>
     <td>56</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td>57</td>
     <td>58</td>
     <td>59</td>
     <td>60</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td>61</td>
     <td>62</td>
     <td>63</td>
     <td>64</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td>65</td>
     <td>66</td>
     <td>67</td>
     <td>68</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td>69</td>
     <td>70</td>
     <td>71</td>
     <td>72</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td>73</td>
     <td>74</td>
     <td>75</td>
     <td>76</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td>77</td>
     <td>78</td>
     <td>79</td>
     <td>80</td>
 </tr>        
 <tr>
     <td>81</td>
     <td>82</td>
     <td>83</td>
     <td>84</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td>85</td>
     <td>86</td>
     <td>87</td>
     <td>88</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td>89</td>
     <td>90</td>
     <td>91</td>
     <td>92</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td>93</td>
     <td>94</td>
     <td>95</td>
     <td>96</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td>97</td>
     <td>98</td>
     <td>99</td>
     <td>100</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td>101</td>
     <td>102</td>
     <td>103</td>
     <td>104</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td>105</td>
     <td>106</td>
     <td>107</td>
     <td>108</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td>109</td>
     <td>110</td>
     <td>111</td>
     <td>112</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td>113</td>
     <td>114</td>
     <td>115</td>
     <td>116</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td>117</td>
     <td>118</td>
     <td>119</td>
     <td>120</td>
 </tr>        
 <tr>
     <td>121</td>
     <td>122</td>
     <td>123</td>
     <td>124</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td>125</td>
     <td>126</td>
     <td>127</td>
     <td>128</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td>129</td>
     <td>130</td>
     <td>131</td>
     <td>132</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td>134</td>
     <td>135</td>
     <td>136</td>
     <td>137</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td>138</td>
     <td>139</td>
     <td>140</td>
     <td>141</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td>142</td>
     <td>143</td>
     <td>144</td>
     <td>145</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td>146</td>
     <td>147</td>
     <td>148</td>
     <td>149</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td>150</td>
     <td>151</td>
     <td>152</td>
     <td>153</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td>154</td>
     <td>155</td>
     <td>156</td>
     <td>157</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td>158</td>
     <td>159</td>
     <td>160</td>
     <td>161</td>
 </tr>        
 <tr>
     <td>162</td>
     <td>163</td>
     <td>164</td>
     <td>165</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td>166</td>
     <td>167</td>
     <td>168</td>
     <td>169</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td>170</td>
     <td>171</td>
     <td>172</td>
     <td>173</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td>174</td>
     <td>175</td>
     <td>176</td>
     <td>177</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td>178</td>
     <td>179</td>
     <td>180</td>
     <td>181</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td>182</td>
     <td>183</td>
     <td>184</td>
     <td>185</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td>186</td>
     <td>187</td>
     <td>188</td>
     <td>189</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td>190</td>
     <td>191</td>
     <td>192</td>
     <td>193</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td>194</td>
     <td>195</td>
     <td>196</td>
     <td>197</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td>198</td>
     <td>199</td>
     <td>200</td>
     <td>201</td>
 </tr>                
     </tbody>
 </table>
```

Jquery

```
            $('table.paginated').each(function () {
              var $table = $(this);
              var itemsPerPage = 10;
              var currentPage = 0;
              var pages = Math.ceil($table.find("tr:not(:has(th))").length / itemsPerPage);
              $table.bind('repaginate', function () {
                if (pages > 1) {
                var pager;
                if ($table.next().hasClass("pager"))
                  pager = $table.next().empty();  else
                pager = $('<div class="pager" style="padding-top: 20px; direction:ltr; " align="center"></div>');

                $('<span class="pg-goto"></span>').text(' « First ').bind('click', function () {
                  currentPage = 0;
                  $table.trigger('repaginate');
                }).appendTo(pager);

                $('<span class="pg-goto"> « Prev </span>').bind('click', function () {
                  if (currentPage > 0)
                    currentPage--;
                  $table.trigger('repaginate');
                }).appendTo(pager);

                var startPager = currentPage > 2 ? currentPage - 2 : 0;
                var endPager = startPager > 0 ? currentPage + 3 : 5;
                if (endPager > pages) {
                  endPager = pages;
                  startPager = pages - 5;    if (startPager < 0)
                    startPager = 0;
                }

                for (var page = startPager; page < endPager; page++) {
                  $('<span id="pg' + page + '" class="' + (page == currentPage ? 'pg-selected' : 'pg-normal') + '"></span>').text(page + 1).bind('click', {
                      newPage: page
                    }, function (event) {
                      currentPage = event.data['newPage'];
                      $table.trigger('repaginate');
                  }).appendTo(pager);
                }

                $('<span class="pg-goto"> Next » </span>').bind('click', function () {
                  if (currentPage < pages - 1)
                  currentPage++;
                  $table.trigger('repaginate');
                }).appendTo(pager);
                $('<span class="pg-goto"> Last » </span>').bind('click', function () {
                  currentPage = pages - 1;
                  $table.trigger('repaginate');
                }).appendTo(pager);

                if (!$table.next().hasClass("pager"))
                  pager.insertAfter($table);
                  //pager.insertBefore($table);

              }// end $table.bind('repaginate', function () { ...

              $table.find(
              'tbody tr:not(:has(th))').hide().slice(currentPage * itemsPerPage, (currentPage + 1) * itemsPerPage).show();
              });

              $table.trigger('repaginate');
            });
```

Comment: Offtopic: bind is deprecated: http://api.jquery.com/bind/ (obsolete since v1.7)

Comment: Also offtopic: Hungarian Notation (System) was generally discouraged in the early 00s... (obv. opinion based, not looking for argument, just saying)

Comment: (on topic :) ) - instead of using `<span ` you could use `<button type='button'` to make them look and act like buttons.  Even if you style the span with css so it "looks" more like a button, it won't act like one without some excessive css/jquery onmousedown/onmouseup code that's already built into `<button>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just change the `span` tags to `button` tags:
[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q6u0rdsc/17/)

Comment: its working fine. but i want to understand how the pager moved to right corner of the table, i dont see any code change . kindly help. Also i wanted to add pager on both top and bottom corner of the table. i have added "pager.insertBefore($table);" but its not working.

Comment: I added some CSS to the pager to get it to the right:
`div.pager {
    text-align: right;
    width: 40em;
    margin: 1em auto;
}`

Comment: insertBefore doesn't copy the element. Your element is just placed somewhere else in the DOM. This is a good question for a new topic.

Can you please mark my answer as the accepted answer?

Comment: Thanks Ruben. I will create a new topic for it.

Answer (score 1):

You can add some CSS code to style like button like this

```
.pager .pg-goto {background: #000; color: #fff; margin: 0 2px; padding: 3px; border-radius: 3px;}
```

You can check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/362gsyxk/) here